# Wifi Hot-spot not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet, 18.04, ap-hotspot

When I create a new AP hot-spot, the devices that try to connect cannot login due authentication error.I'm connected via ethernet with static IP configuration.

I followed [these steps](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/05/create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-android-support/)

These steps creates me a WPA network.

The Ubuntu installation is new and fully updated.

Comment: @pomsky That link was useful, thanks, I've used the nm-connection-editor  to delete the default wifi network that ubuntu creates for the AP hot-spot and create a new one with the settings that I need.